# UITableView in AutoLayed Out Xib Crops in 3.5-Inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout

I have an app that uses navigation controllers and a tab bar controller. So my view controllers all have navigation bars and tab bars.

When I add a UITableView to a UIViewController, *then run the simulator for a 3.5-inch screen*, the following happens

1. The top of the table doesn't start at the of the UIViewController (right underneath the navigation bar)
2. The bottom content (if I had more than one page and scrolled to the bottom) gets cut of
3. If I use a style == Grouped, then the top header always gets cut off

To see what I mean, try these steps:

1. Create a new file of type UIViewController with a xib
2. Make sure AutoLayout is checked
3. In interface designer, set simulated metrics to have a translucent top bar and a bottom tab bar.
4. Add a UITableView to the cell
5. Add some data in it so you can see the data and scroll
6. Run the app

Can anyone help provide guidance as to how to fix these issues? Are y'all getting these problems too or is it just me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it reproduces on iOS 7 place that in your's view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // To support iOS 6
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
         self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually makes it a lot worse.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots?